# How to programmatically trigger onclick event

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

How can I programmatically trigger onclick/oncompleted event? E.g.

```
<p:commandButton value="Destroy the World" onclick="confirmation.show()" type="button"/>  

<p:confirmDialog message="Are you sure about destroying the world?"  
                 showEffect="bounce" hideEffect="explode"  
                 header="Initiating destroy process" severity="alert" widgetVar="confirmation">
</p:confirmDialog>
```

I'm trying to trigger `onclick="confirmation.show()"` from a backing bean.
I'm using JSF2/Primefaces 2.2.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `oncomplete` attribute instead of `onclick` of the commandButton.  The click javascript event occurs before the page posts back, likely causing your dialog not to appear because of the page reloading.

`oncomplete="confirmation.show()"` will display the dialog AFTER the postback.

Answer (score 0):

Since the click contains only one call, you can call the code directly:

```
confirmation.show();
```

But if you want to do it your way and if you use jQuery, you can simply do:

```
$('p[type=button]').click();
```